# In-App simple tutorial

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, libgdx

I want to use Google In-App billing for my Android Apps using Libgdx. By default, it is a free apps for everyone. Some of the features will be unlocked once user paid a small fee (lets assume $1), and all features will be unlocked if user paid the full price (assuming $2).

I have a read on [official Google's Billing site](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html) but I have no idea how to link it to Libgdx. The [Official Libgdx Site](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/Billing) doesn't really provide any clear instruction and explanation.

As at today, I still have no idea on how to link both Libgdx and In-App Billing. Furthermore, where is the information being stored (is it in the preference file?) when user purchased the unlocked item? I have absolutely no idea.

It will be great if someone lead me to the right path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Libgdx has an extension library that provides in-app-billing services in a cross-platform way: https://github.com/libgdx/gdx-pay.  You can use this as-is, or use it as an example for how to interface between core and platform-specific code.

Answer (score 6):

Read about the Libgdx way for [Interfacing with Platform Specific Code](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code).

Basically, you need to implement the in-app billing support within your Android project, and then expose an API to your platform-independent code to access whatever state you need.  There really isn't anything libgdx-specific about the result, the billing code will all exist in your Android back-end, so most existing Android documentation and tutorials should apply.

See this forum post for a few more details:
http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=2544

Also, when searching, in Libgdx-land this is often called "IAP" support (for "in-app purchasing").

Comment: Thanks @p-t. I will try that later. however, there is something i am not sure, should the IAP modify the application preference or separate file (should be encrypted, right?). And does user need to repurchase the function again if user re-download my App (like change phone)?

Comment: Those are good questions, but do not, I think, have anything to do with Libgdx, and are not questions I know the answer to.  Try searching in the [android] [in-app-billing] sections of SO.

Comment: @P.T. do you have any sample for Libgdx Android In-App purchase?