# Libgdx and google IAP

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, libgdx

As per @P.T. suggestion on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19921146/libgdx-android-in-app-simple-tutorial), in order to link Google IAP (In-Apps Purchase) with Libgdx, where should I place the IInAppBillingService.aidl and all the other util files (TriviaDriveSample.util\files)? Should I place it in my main java project (assuming greatGame) or my android project (assuming greatGame-android)? I am currently facing issue integrating Libgdx and Google IAP.

Can some guru please lead me to the destination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of them go into the Android project. For example this is my hierarchy:

MyGame-Android
..-src
....-com
......-android
........-vending
..........-billing
............*IInAppBillingService.aidl
......-my
........-package
..........-util
............*utilfiles...
..........*MainActivity.java

This is because to handle IAP you need to use android specific code in the android project, and interfacing it from the core. Go here for more info about it: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code

Comment: Thanks @Lestat , that helps. I have no problem following TrivialDrive instruction on IAP but I am clueless in integrating both IAP and Libgdx. I am not sure which part is handle by Libgdx and/or android. As an example (TrivialDrive), in libgdx, where should I place the PublicKey? Do I still need to declare IabHelper mHelper, in Core or Android? How do I call the “launchPurchaseFlow(this, SKU_BUYCLICK, RC_REQUEST, mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload)”? do I call it from Core or Android?
Currently I am running around like a headless chicken, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I can't even resolve labHelper, did you have any luck?